# Duplicate files copied android studio when change version google play service

Tags: android

In my application I user google play service ads and service gcm  and a lib user google play service 8.4.0.
When I user version 8.4.0 for google play service ads and gcm it run, but when I change it from 8.4.0 to 10.2.0 it can't run and show error

```js
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml
 File1: D:\PROJECT\koshien_android\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-basement\10.2.0\jars\classes.jar
 File2: D:\PROJECT\koshien_android\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\koshien_android\lib-movie-player\unspecified\jars\classes.jar
```

How I can fix my error.

Comment: Make sure you have updated the version of other dependencies version too.

Comment: add gradle file code here so it will be easy to provide you solution.

Comment: you have to update the library's dependency too

Comment: Tks you very much , I did it, I added
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
       }
and it run